# NSJSONSerialization Error : Why am I not able to catch the error in try catch block? swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I am calling REST API to get a response from the server and also testing for bad data type to caught in try catch block nut app still crashes with below error:

> > Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10575ee00) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10575f2d8).

```
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        do {

           let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String,String>

            print(responseObject)

        } catch let jsonError {

            print(jsonError)
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
```

For this, I also found the solution that I should check data with JSON format first then use JSONSerialization.

```
if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(data){
    responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<String,String>

}
else {

    print("Error")

}
```

**I want to know that if type cast value error not caught by the try-catch block then what is a use of try-catch block in network call.** I can simply check for the `JSON` format and the pass the response object.

**What is a good programming practice?**

NOTE : Error is not an issue I just don't want my should crash an app when data type changes form dictionary to array or other than specified type.

Answer (score 2):

This is not about valid `JSON`, you are getting this crash because your `JSON` at root is `Array` not `Dictionary` and you are trying to cast the result of `jsonObject(with:)` to `Dictionary` that is the reason you are getting this crash also there is no need to specify `mutableContainers` with Swift.

```
do {

    let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
    print(responseObject)

} catch let jsonError {

    print(jsonError)
}
```

**Edit:** If you don't know your `JSON` time then you can use if let like this way.

```
do {

    let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseArray = responseObject as? [[String:Any]] {
        //Access array
    }
    else if let responseDictionary = responseObject as? [String:Any] {
        //Access dictionary
    }
    print(responseObject)

} catch let jsonError {

    print(jsonError)
}
```

Comment: then it should catch in try catch block but app crashes

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre Can you show on which line it is crashing, also you need to show us your `JSON` response

Comment: Error is not an issue I just don't want my should crash an app when data type changes form dictionary to array or other than specified type.

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre the cast failure is not an exception, it's a runtime error that causes an abort. There is no way to catch it or recover. That's the danger of using `as!` instead of `as?`. If you want to detect the problem, then you must use `as?`.

Comment: @NiravD I know it will work but what is a use of try-catch block. I want to catch error when data type changes form specified type.

Comment: @JefferyThomas when i use `as?` it will send response object `nil`. I want to show data type error. Thanks to server guy

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre You cannot handle that crash with Try catch block, you need to either use `if let` or `guard let`

Comment: @NiravD Thanks for your response. Then the only way to get rid of wrong data format using if else.

Comment: @SiddheshMhatre Yes Try catch will not help you in this case unless you make your own Custom Error handling